# Adding a static block messing up footer?

Tags: magento2, static-block, footer

I am trying to edit the category page on my Magento 2.3 site. I use the pearl theme. I took out all the default text and pictures and called a static block. The static block looks how I want, which is great. However, now the footer gets called in the middle of page. I cleared the cache and the issue still persists. [image]

Comment: Check if you have any unclosed `div` tags in your static block.

Comment: okay so there was a missing </div> tag but now the header and the footer are very messed up

Answer (score 0):

If you hard code a height in the css section of the block editing, it will affect the layout of the rest of the page.